# avast disappear and doesn't re-install/uninstall/repair

Tags: windows-8.1, anti-virus, windows-defender, avast, avira

It happened this morning: Avast Antivirus Free just disappeared from tray icon ?!

I checked the installation directories, and everything is in there, but the antivirus didn't started.

I tried to repair/uninstall, through Control Panel, but it show me an error message.

I tried to use Avast Clear, from here http://files.avast.com/iavs9x/avastclear.exe, but it stuck in the first screen.

I tried to use it again, in Safe Mode, but it stuck again.

So, in safe mode, I removed "all" avast entryies in register, restarted the computer and installed Avira. (But I prefer Avast)

I am using: Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit.

The last Windows Update is: Windows Defender KB2267602, but it shows an error, and I'm think this messed up with Avast.

Does anyone know what could be happened ?

Comment: Do you have System Restore enabled?

Comment: no. I want to know what happened to prevent it.

Comment: "but it show me an error message." - This does not tell us very much.  Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

after a [search on google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=antivirus+turning+itself+off), you are one of many people with this issue.

The answer to the question "Why it happened?" is not simple.

From [Microsoft's blog](https://blogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2013/07/25/why-does-my-av-software-keep-turning-off/):

1. Your computer is already infected with rogue security software
2. You have more than one antivirus program
3. You might have a virus

This issue can occurs with Avast, Avira, AVG, Kasperky, Defender, and others.

Comment: Can you provide any methods that will help determine the real cause, or that can be used to repair the system?